# How to download multiple files from S3 as Zip format in Rails 5.x.x app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, zip

I am implementing feature which allows user to either download single file or multiple files from S3.
Single file downloading is working properly, but for multiple files I am receiving error on Heroku,

`Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat )`

Controller code snippet for downloading files as zip format is as below,

```
def method_name
   zipfile_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/archive.zip"
   Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile |
     @transfer.transfer_attachments.each do |attachment | 
       zipfile.add(attachment.avatar.file.filename, attachment.avatar.url)
     end
   end
   send_file(File.join("#{Rails.root}/public/", 'archive.zip'), : type =>
'application/zip', : filename => "#{Time.now.to_date}.zip")
end
```

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'

gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.0.0'

gem 'zip-zip'
```

This zipfile functionality works proper with locally stored files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to answer to my question.
Steps are as follow,

1. Downlaod files from S3 and store them locally
2. Add them to zip by first creating zip and then add files to it.
3. Download zip archive

Here is controller code,

```
require 'open-uri'

def download_all_files
   folder_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/downloads/"
   zipfile_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/archive.zip"

   FileUtils.remove_dir(folder_path) if Dir.exist?(folder_path)
   FileUtils.remove_entry(zipfile_name) if File.exist?(zipfile_name)
   Dir.mkdir("#{Rails.root}/public/downloads")

   @model_object.each do |attachment|
      open(folder_path + "#{attachment.avatar.file.filename}", 'wb') do |file|
         file << open("#{attachment.avatar.url}").read
      end
   end

   input_filenames = Dir.entries(folder_path).select {|f| !File.directory? f}

   Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      input_filenames.each do |attachment|
         zipfile.add(attachment,File.join(folder_path,attachment))
      end
   end

   send_file(File.join("#{Rails.root}/public/", 'archive.zip'), :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "#{Time.now.to_date}.zip")

end
```

Comment: Do you know how one can give a custom name to each file being zipped?

Comment: Thank you. Yes you can do it while adding files to zip folder.

Comment: depending on the size of the file(s) and number of users, it might not work for volumes that are a little high!?

Answer (score 2):

Guess: You are adding attachments as urls, but you should be adding (local) file paths instead.

Comment: All the files are uploaded to S3. And in `zipfile.add()` I am passing filename and its actual URL (Stored on S3). One other important thing is, this code works properly with locally stored files.

Comment: That's what I meant to say: you probably have to download the files from S3 first before the zip library can add them to your zipfile.

Comment: Yes got it. I will implement it. Thanks